# Report on Actual WSUS Deployment

Tags: wsus

I note from [this Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708497(v=ws.10).aspx) that the term "Installed" means, as you would think, that the update installed successfully. However, the term "Installed/Not Applicable" just means, in fact, not applicable.

Is this the correct interpretation of this? If so, I note that *none* of my updates report a status of Installed. Ever. I only get the other categories.

So with that in mind, is there a way in WSUS to report on the actual deployment status of an update? I have an optional update that I urgently need deployed to all my workstations (it's a project dependency). Spot checks of workstations show they don't have it, I need a more granular (and focused, excluding other updates would be good) way of reporting on this.

EDIT: There is a section at the end of [this Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720459(v=ws.10).aspx) on extending reports. Is this the only of achieving anything usable out of WSUS reporting?